# Click outside - PIXI JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events, pixi.js

So I'm trying to create a "popup-like" component on PIXI js, so what happens is I have a button, I click the button, I toggle the visibility of that container.

Now My problem is, I want it so if I click outside the container, the container will close. I tried most of the events here: https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.interaction.InteractionManager.html

But I wasn't able to find what I want.

The problem is that I can't just add events outside that container because I have a ton of other components too.

Anyone here might have an idea or maybe a library for this?

**UPDATE**: I don't have any HTML element (that is written by me) on my project, they are all handled by PIXIjs inside the canvas and I am using [Container](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html) / [Graphics](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html) for the view/layout.

Answer (score 0):

below is javascript working code

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (document.getElementById('container_id')) {
          if (document.getElementById('container_id').contains(e.target)) {
            // Clicked in box

          } else {
            // Clicked outside the box

          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear but I don't have any html element (that is written by me) on my project, I am using PIXI js and draw on canvas, hence this is not the answer I'm looking for - This might be useful for other usage with html elements tho. I updated the question.

Comment: It was clear to me... you said PIXI js
The answer did not address PIXI js at all